# How to tell which URLs have fallen out of search engine index

Tags: sitemap, search-engine-indexing

I've had a few pages trimmed from google's indexed number on my sitemap in webmaster tools. How can I tell which pages have been dropped?

Answer (score 4):

You can find out what pages Google indexes by searching Google for "site:yoursite.com" or "site:www.yoursite.com" if you use the www prefix. You could compare this list with your sitemap to discover which pages were dropped.

There are paid tools available, like the [Index Checker,](http://www.index-checker.com/index.php) that claim to find which of your pages are indexed and which aren't. (Haven't used it, so I can't offer a personal recommendation.)

Comment: I think that solution should work. Specifically changing the number of returned results to 100 and copying the entire google page, then filtering everything except the URL in excel would do it. Wish there was an easier way to just get the returned URLs without all the titles and descriptions.

Comment: Odd, but I tried this and more URLs showed up by using site:mywebsite.com than google lists as being indexed in webmaster tools. That's seems a bit odd.